# Converting table with coordinates raster plot

Tags: r, reshape, raster

I'm a total beginner and have what I believe is a rather simple problem, but I am kind of stuck...

I have a data table with three columns: `x`, `y` and `height` values. I've imported the csv file and extracted the values:

```
data <- read.csv("C:/Data/heights.csv")
mydata <- data[, c("x", "y", "height")]
```

I then need to put the `height` values into a grid with these coordinates, which I created as a raster:

```
grid <- raster(ncol=2001, nrow=2001, xmn=479975, xmx=500025, ymn=119975, ymx=140025)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are very close. I'd suggest you reading the raster package material, the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf) and [description](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf).

You'll have to pay attention to your data and how it is organized. By row? Column? raster cells values will be populated by row.

Using something simmilar to the example provided in the help `?raster`

```
library(raster)
vals <- 1:100
r1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10, xmn=479975, xmx=500025, ymn=119975, ymx=140025)
r1[] <- vals
plot(r1)
```

[image]

But the procedure may be different approaching with a spatial object

```
library(sp)
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(x=x,y=y), v=1:100)
coordinates(df)=~x+y
gridded(df) = TRUE
r2 <- raster(df)
plot(r2)
```

[image: raster from a spatial object]

I think this may be the best approach but it would be better to have an idea about your data and how it is organized.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
library(raster)
x <- rasterFromXYZ(mydata)
extent(x) <- c(479975, 500025, 119975, 140025)
```